# Should questions about publication be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Publishing is a central point of Computer Science (well, probably any science), so should this site allow questions about publication issues (this could include any sort of publication, e.g. conferences, theses, journals, ...) that are directly related, and specific to, Computer Science?

Comment: general questions about publishing are probably more suitable for [academia.se], but if it is CS specific then I don't see any reason to make them off-topic.

Comment: @Kaveh: General questions, yes. But specific CS related questions may be, well, too specific for academia.

Comment: Is this on topic at CSTheory?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, they are on-topic on [cstheory.se] (as long as they are in the scope: theoretical and research-level). ps: I think a more appropriate example to follow for [cs.se] is [math.se].

Answer (score 3):

Publishing is a central point of computer science *research*. I believe [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) allows questions about the theoretical CS academic community, so questions specifically about publications in TCS could go there. For general questions about academic matters, including publication, ask on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). Even if the question is domain-specific, that is an appropriate venue.

I don't think questions about publication should be on-topic here. This is a site about computer science, not about the social processes around research on computer science.

Answer (score 2):

It's my impression that this site was designed to fill the gap between SO (a professional CS community/programming community) and [the theoretical CS Stack Exchange site](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), which is for "research-level questions in theoretical computer science." Therefore, the purpose of this site seems more for undergraduates, for whom publishing is decidedly not a concern. I say publishing questions should go to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com (if they'll welcome them) or the Academia SE site mentioned earlier.

Comment: Their FAQ doesn't say anything explicitly about pubs, a search shows a few questions about it. We'll see about getting an opinion from the mods there.

Comment: not every question about publishing is research-level or theory related.

Comment: @Kaveh could you provide an example where publishing is not research-level (whether it is theoretical or not is immaterial, I think)?

Comment: @Rafe, let me think (it might be difficult to find a good example). But if it is not theoretical then it is not suitable for cstheory. By the way, I don't see why we would like to forbid such questions as long as they are not causing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing your findings in the most general sense is an integral part of knowledge aggregation and transfer. I think we should support people as best we can with that, as long as the question deals with a specific, computer science related issue (say, for instance, notation or which prior knowledge to assume).

General questions about academic publishing should probably go to academia.SE, though.